# How can I group a field in subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, group-by, lookup

I have the following document:

```
{
    "_id": "5a5cae1890254804e3a4655d", 
    "additional_ingredient": {
        "concentration": 40.0, 
        "formulations": [
            "5a1826c664f7fe04afbe9198"
        ]
    }
}
```

Inside `additional_ingredient` there is an array field `formulations`. When I have an array field in the first level of a document I can use `$unwind` then `$lookup` to join an external document and the group by this field.

But I cannot do the same with a nested array. What is the best solution for that?

What I expect:

```
{
    "_id": "5a5cae1890254804e3a4655d", 
    "additional_ingredient": {
        "concentration": 40.0, 
        "formulations": [
            {
                "_id": "5a1826c664f7fe04afbe9198", 
                "date_created": "Fri, 24 Nov 2017 14:03:50 GMT", 
                "date_modified": "Fri, 24 Nov 2017 14:03:50 GMT", 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have a problem with grouping. `The field name 'additional_ingredient.formulations' cannot contain '.'`

This is a part of the query:

```
            {"$unwind": "$additional_ingredient.formulations"},
            self.__ADDITIONAL_INGREDIENT_FORMULATION_LOOKUP_QUERY,
            {"$unwind": "$additional_ingredient.formulations"},
            {"$group": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "additional_ingredient.formulations": {"$push": "$additional_ingredient.formulations"},
            }},
```

Comment: `$unwind` on nested array also work. Use `{"$unwind": "additional_ingredient.formulations" }`

Comment: I have a problem during grouping. 
` The field name 'additional_ingredient.formulations' cannot contain '.'`

Comment: it's not clear, you may want to add your query here or open an other question with more details

Comment: That was a typo by @felix. They meant: `{"$unwind": "$additional_ingredient.formulations" }`. All field path expressions need the `$`, otherwise they are just a string.

Comment: On another note, why are you doing `$unwind` **before** the `$lookup`? This was an issue in older MongoDB versions, but it's been fixed for a while. Try doing the `$lookup` without the `$unwind` first, so you don't have multiple `$unwind` operations slowing things down. It's fine before a `$group`, but you should not need it before that.

Comment: @neil-lunn Thanks for your note about `$unwind` before `$lookup`. Fixed. But still, don't know how to group a nested field .

Comment: You cannot use a "dotted" field name as the target for an accumulator. You need to do something like: `"formulations": {"$push": "$additional_ingredient.formulations"}`. If you want a nested output, you need to rename that with a subsequent `$project` or like stage (`$addFields`, `$replaceRoot`).